# Can't seem to figure out why I can't read JSON into DataFrame

Tags: python, json, pandas

How would I convert the "Data" section of this JSON to a simple pandas table. Here's what I have:

```
import json
import urllib.request
import pandas

url = urllib.request.urlopen('https://www.cryptocompare.com/api/data/coinlist/')
json_obj = json.load(url)
print(json.dumps(json_obj, sort_keys=True, indent=4))

json_data = json_obj['Data']
print(json.dumps(json_data, sort_keys=True, indent=4))

df = pandas.DataFrame(json_data)
with pandas.option_context('display.max_rows', None, 'display.max_columns', 3):
    print(df)
```

Tried a bunch of ways but the result doesn't look correct. The table should be:

```
CoinName,Algorithm,...
ABC,          AAA, ...
DEF,          DDS, ...
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Looks good to me

```
pandas.DataFrame(json_obj['Data']).T

          Algorithm          CoinName                 FullName FullyPremined  
007          Scrypt          007 coin           007 coin (007)             0   
1337            X13              1337              1337 (1337)             0   
1CR          Scrypt           1Credit            1Credit (1CR)             0   
1ST             N/A        FirstBlood         FirstBlood (1ST)             1   
2015            X11         2015 coin         2015 coin (2015)             0   
2BACCO       Scrypt       2BACCO Coin     2BACCO Coin (2BACCO)             0   
2GIVE        Scrypt         2GiveCoin        2GiveCoin (2GIVE)             0   
32BIT           X11         32Bitcoin        32Bitcoin (32BIT)             0   
365             X11           365Coin            365Coin (365)             0   
404          Scrypt           404Coin            404Coin (404)             0   
42           Scrypt           42 Coin             42 Coin (42)             0   
611          SHA256         SixEleven          SixEleven (611)             0   
808          SHA256               808                808 (808)             0   
888             N/A          Octocoin           Octocoin (888)             0
```

Comment: Ugh.. was missing the .T

Answer (score 0):

Not a full answer, but I don’t have the reputation to leave a comment.

urllib.request.urlopen is returning an object but json.load is expecting a string.

If you are looking for a string you must be using the wrong method.
https://docs.python.org/3.4/library/urllib.request.html?highlight=urllib.request.urlopen#urllib.request.urlopen

```
>>> json_obj = json.load(url)
Traceback (most recent call last):
File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
File  "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.6/lib/python3.6/json/__init__.py", line 268, in load
parse_constant=parse_constant, object_pairs_hook=object_pairs_hook, **kw)
File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.6/lib/python3.6/json/__init__.py", line 312, in loads
s.__class__.__name__))
TypeError: the JSON object must be str, not 'bytes'    
>>> url.info()
<http.client.HTTPMessage object at 0x105ab3518>    
>>> url.getcode()
200
```

Answer (score 0):

Once you have read the JSON, you now actually have a Python `dict` in `json_data`. Therefore, you need [`pandas.DataFrame.from_dict`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.from_dict.html#pandas.DataFrame.from_dict):

```
df = pandas.DataFrame.from_dict(json_obj['Data'], orient='index')
```